# Bind an outside reference to thread object lifetime

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference

I have implemented a thread class that does some operations on an task object and reports back on these operations via event callbacks.
In these callbacks I have to include some legacy code that's outside of my control.

|task| <--- |thread|

```
public void onDone(T& task)
{
  legacyCode();
}
```

Now, on application destruction I always wait for the threads to finish and then exit clean. This works very well on the device (embedded) its supposed to run on, but it quite frequently crashes in the unit test environment because the destructor has a different member  destruction order as the production code. Specifically there's a reference that gets deleted before my thread finishes and the test crashes.

How can I bind an outside reference to my thread object? I'm not looking for code examples, this is more of an architectural problem. I can't change legacy code, so I have to work with what I got.

Comment: Need more details. What kind of reference, how legacy objects lifetime is managed, which destructor crashes (thread, task...) etc

Comment: Just a normal reference. What happens is that the unit test destructor will remove said reference before the thread finishes, when in the production application the reference gets removed after the application.

Comment: So you have to change unit test and join (wait to finish) that thread before unit test exits.

Comment: @Rost Yeah, that's what I did in the end. It's not pretty because generally there shouldn't be any functionality between the test and the software, just interfaces.